# Remove unused images in database from disk

Tags: php, mysql

I have over 100k images to check, but after a few checks (like 100) the script stops. How can I use a certain limit to let the script keep working without deleting exiting images ?

Here is my code:

```
$images = scandir("../upload", 1);

foreach ($images as $itemlc) 
{
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE rimage='$itemlc'"); 
    $count = mysql_num_rows($res); 
    if($count == 0)
    {
        $file_path = '../images/';
        $src=$file_path.$itemlc;    
        @unlink($src);
        echo $itemlc; echo " <b>deleted</b> <br> ";     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides setting

```
set_time_limit(0);  //if safe mode off
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //if safe mode on
```

you should index the column on which you use WHERE (at least temporary).

Or use single query to pull data in simple array and then check it from this array if your server is very weak.

and please, run it from command line if you can

```
php index.php
```

to see faster output